# Statusbar background was nil,after presenting the SKStoreProductViewController in ios 8.4

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar, appstore-sandbox, ios8.4

I'm using SKStoreProductViewController for opening the appstore in my app. it was presenting successfully,but the statusbar in it was not showing, Navbar looks like a 44pixels height. But it won't happens in any iOS 8.3v in any device.
This situation happens only in all iOS 8.4v devices.

In my plist UIViewControllerBasedStatusbarAppearance is set to NO. i tried with Yes also, but no use.

[image]

the Red color in status bar is superview navigationbar color.

NOTE: i'm presenting the SKStoreProductViewController from my ParentViewController.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding statusBar as UIView Component, Its a workaround to the solution. I also faced similar issue.

```
   SKStoreProductViewController *_apsvc = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc]init];
    _apsvc.delegate = self;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];

        //change this to match your navigation bar

        UIViewController* viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewController.view.frame.size.width, 20);

        addStatusBar.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];


    }


    UIViewController* viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    if (viewController)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController  presentViewController:_apsvc animated:YES completion:^()
         {

             [_apsvc loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : AppID}
                  completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
                      if(error)
                      {
                         ....
                      }
                  }];
              [viewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];

         }];

    }

}


    -(void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController    *)viewController
   {
        [addStatusBar removeFromSuperview];
       if (viewController)
       { 
       [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       }
    }
```

Comment: create UIView *addStatusBar outside, so that it will be accessible in delegate methods also...